# Xamarin Android view pdf in layout using Mupdf

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin.android, mupdf

I want to use MuPDF reader for my Xamarin Android project .
I am attempting to view a PDF in my relative layout

Here is my Relative layout code

```
  <RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/mupdf_wrapper"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </RelativeLayout>
```

and here is main acitivity

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        RelativeLayout mupdfWrapper = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mupdf_wrapper);



        MuPDFCore core = new MuPDFCore(this, "test.pdf");
        MuPDFReaderView reader = new MuPDFReaderView(this);
        reader.Adapter = new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, new FilePicker.IFilePickerSupport() , core);
        mupdfWrapper.AddView(reader);

        mupdfWrapper.AddView(reader);
```

But i am getting Error here

"cannot create an istance of the abstract class or interface 'File picker .iflepickersupport"

Can anyone help me resolve this issue please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What* error are you getting?

Comment: thank you ,error in this line    reader.Adapter = new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, new FilePicker.IFilePickerSupport() , core);  it says "cannot create an istance of the abstract class or  interface  'File picker .iflepickersupport'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have use of FilePicker.IFilePickerSupport() then set it null
like

```
reader.Adapter = new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, null , core);
```

and second thing is that your code is very helpful for me there you are facing problem but your problem is my solution in my project so thank you.
and try it it will work and i am using it in my code it's work for me.
and last this thing is that sorry for my english.

```
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                File fileToDisplay = (File)fileFromAsset(this, "test.pdf");
                fileToDisplay.SetWritable(true);
                RelativeLayout mupdfWrapper = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.mupdf_wrapper);
                MuPDFCore core = new MuPDFCore(this, fileToDisplay.AbsolutePath);

                MuPDFReaderView reader = new MuPDFReaderView(this);
                MuPDFPageAdapter adapter = new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, null, core);
                reader.SetAdapter(adapter);
                mupdfWrapper.AddView(reader);
    }

    private object fileFromAsset(Context context, string assetName)
    {
        File outFile = new File(context.CacheDir, assetName);
        copy(context.Assets.Open(assetName), outFile);
        return outFile;
    }

    private void copy(Stream inputStream, File output)
    {
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        var bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        try
        {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = bufferedInputStream.Read(bytes)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if (inputStream != null)
                {
                    inputStream.Close();                  
                    inputStream.Dispose();
                    inputStream = null;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (outputStream != null)
                {
                    outputStream.Close();                        
                    outputStream.Dispose();
                    outputStream = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you vishal ,when i deploy it says "cannot open test.pdf file ", so may  you have another way , this code isnot working for me

Comment: so is you are opening this file from assets then use code. i edit my answer.

Comment: thank you vishal really you helped so much  but still i am getting error it says " MuPDFReaderView' does not contain a definition for 'SetAdapter' and no extension method 'SetAdapter' accepting a first argument of type 'MuPDFReaderView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: ohhh sorry brother so sorry i forget to mention about using com.Artifex.MuPdf version just add new latest version of it from nuget package manager and it's resolve. and then  it is using like
using Artifex.MuPdf;

Comment: when i try to install latest version it says " Object refrence not set to an instance of an object " so i can't install latest version but version 1 is working for me any help  please

Comment: `
 MuPDFReaderView reader = new MuPDFReaderView(this);
        reader.Adapter = new MuPDFPageAdapter(this, null , core);
        mupdfWrapper.AddView(reader);
`

Comment: vishal Still i am getting this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." even when i use my old code

Comment: can u please specify where you are get this object reference error??

Comment: When I deploy pop up will appear there is no error when I build its only when. I deploy could you please send your project, I have tried a lot still nothing is working Actually I only need to add custom toolbar my email is mohamedzardheye@gmail.com

Comment: Still i am waiting for you brother vishal

Comment: sorry brother due to heavy work load i can't send you mail toady i will send you mail.

Comment: welcome. and if you got then please mark as right answer :)